# How to use checkbox implement different functions at same time JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am fresh with JavaScript, and a little bit confusing with the language about JavaScript, JQuery, Vanilla JavaScript. I have two checkbox in one html, and I have two different function for each checkbox. What should I do to correct this function?

HTML code:

```
<div class = "multianswer">
  <input type = "checkbox" name = "answercheck" id= "answercheck">
  <label for = "answercheck"> Show Answers </label>
</div>


<div class = "multifeature">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="featurescheck" id="featurescheck">
  <label for = "featurescheck"> Show More Features </label>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
    $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
            $("input:checkbox:checked").click(function(){ 

//I think is some problem about this ***(function), because if I put 
// ".each(function)", all the checkbox and the function is working. And I 
//  have tried use checkbox id to identify each checkbox, but it is not 
//  working, don't understand why? 

                showAnswer()  //This is the one of the functions
            })
        })

    $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
            $("input:checkbox:checked").click(function(){  //same as above
                showMoreFeatures()  //This is another function
            })
        })
```

Consider the final effect what I want, I think there have two key questions:
1. as the code shown, how to make each checkbox working different functions.
2. This two function will achieve different effect in one text area, and I am hoping these two effect could show together, do not be covered by each other.So this is why I use checkbox, but how to achieve this I still don't know.

Thanks for the help~

Added information: This is the two function, but after I checked it, I still don't think the problem is here if I want to show two effect together

```
        function showAnswer(){
            var answerWords=$(".final .answer p").text();
            var text= $(".article p").text(); 
            var txt1 = answerWords;
            var txt2 = '<span style = "background-color:yellow">' + txt1 + '</span >'
            var reg = new RegExp(txt1,"g")
            text = text.replace(reg ,txt2)

            $(".article p").html(text) 

        };

        function showMoreFeatures(){
            var text= $(".article p").text(); 
            var qus = item2.question;
            var newCheckQus = new Array();
            var subQus= qus.substr(0,qus.length-1);
            var checkQus = subQus.split(" ");

            for(var i =0; i < checkQus.length; i++){
                if(except.indexOf(checkQus[i]) >-1){
                    continue    
                }else{
                    var txt2 = '<span style = "background-color:#2ECCFA">' + checkQus[i] + '</span >'
                    var reg = new RegExp(checkQus[i] ,"g")
                    text = text.replace(reg ,txt2)
                }   
                }

                $(".article p").html(text)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the checkbox checked using the following prop - and the execute code if true

```js
$("#featurescheck").change(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        //your code here;
    } else {
        //your code here
    }
});
$("#answeredcheck").change(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        //your code here;
    } else {
        //your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, It is working, but still have one problem, is as the question's key point 2, the two function's effect just be covered by each other, one is implemented and when I checked another one, the first effect will gone. How to fix this problem? Thanks, other wise is it enough just set check box? I should improve my function?  my two function is replace different color for different word in text, some of them will get yellow background, and some of them will get another color background, and I need show all the color finally.

Answer (score 0):

You could get if checkbox is checked or unchecked in one single event.Use the click event instead of the change event.

Updated <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQQdH/1007/)</kbd>   .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr("id") === "answercheck"){
     if( $(this).attr("checked")){
      alert('answercheck checked');
    }
    else{
      alert('answercheck unchecked');
    }
    }
   if($(this).attr("id") === "featurescheck" ){
    if( $(this).attr("checked")){
      alert('featurescheck checked');
    }
    else{
      alert('featurescheck unchecked');
    }
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, follow this way, it is not working, even not working to call the function. but it will working to call the function if I change "attr" to "prop". with on click function. But the final effect still get covered, only can show on color(one function effect, not two )

Comment: Thanks very very much for the update , but still have the problem is they get covered. For example, the show answer function will get some word yellow, and show features function will get some word blue, all these words in one text area, and final effect , after I checked all these two checkbox, should be in this text area shown yellow and blue words. But now, I only can get blue or yellow when I checked them ,depend on which one is the last, then the color will remain.